# HQL query for non-standard ManyToMany relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql

I have ManyToMany relationship between **Author** and **Book**.
table :**AUTHOR**
*id | name*

table :**ASSIGN**
*id | author_id | book_id*

table : **BOOK**
*id | title*

But I am using not standart ManyToMany mapping, I am using next

```
class Book
{
   @Id
   long id;

   String title;

   @OneToMany
   List<Assign> authors;
}

class Assign
{
   @Id
   long id;

   @ManyToOne
   Book book

   @ManyToOne
   Author author;
}

class Author
{
   @Id
   long id;

   String name;

   @OneToMany
   List<Assign> books;
}
```

What is query to get all Books for Author's name? Also What is query to get all Books' names for Author's name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have two OneToMany associations. You just need to use joins in your query, as described in the [Hibernate documentation over HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins).

```
select book from Author author 
left join author.books assign
left join assign.book book
where author.name = :name
```

The second query is the same, except you just want the book names:

```
select book.name from Author author ...
```

Side note: you shouldn't name your collection of Assigns `books` or `authors`: it's very confusing. Name it `assigns`.

Comment: in the end ' where book.title = :title '. Yep, it's true

Answer (score 0):

*What is query to get all Books for Author's name?*

from Book b order by b.authors.author.name

*What is query to get all Books' names for Author's name?*

select b.title from Book b order by b.authors.author.name

Have you swapped title and name in Author and Book classes?